# Unity2d: SmoothDamp not moving to Lerp-ed calculated position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
travelTime = 0.0f;
            while (Vector3.Distance(Vector2.Lerp(startPos, endPos, travelTime), transform.position) >= maxDistance) {
                locationToGo = Vector2.Lerp(startPos, Input.mousePosition, travelTime);
                travelTime += 0.1f;
            }
            // SHOW
            // Smoothly move the camera towards that target position
            transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, locationToGo, ref velocity, smoothTime);
```

So, this code is meant to use Lerp to return a Vector2 a certain amount of 'steps' towards the mouse pointer. And then give that value to the SmoothDamp to move the square to the pos. But the Lerp is not calculating correctly. Does anyone know what is wrong, or any better working alternatives?

Comment: You know that your entire while loop will be executed in one single go within one single frame right? Also for the condition you use `endPose` but for the calculation of `locationToGo` you directly use `Input.mousePosition` .. how are they related? Then the next time you call this again the entire while loop is executed again which will change the value since the transform was moved in the meantime ... What exactly are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to make the square move x amount of steps towards the mouse pointer. And it is meant to change it is executed every mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't really know what exactly you are trying to achieve i'm just gonna guess you want to move a GameObject to the MousePosition every Frame.
You could do it like this (it is out of my head, not compileproof):

```
GameObject ourGameobject;
Vector3 ourTarget;
void Update() 
{
    ourGameobject.transform.position = Vector3.lerp(ourGameobject.transform.position, ourTarget, Time.DeltaTime);
}
```

For faster or lower speed just multiply `Time.DeltaTime` with sth.

Also Note that `Input.MousePosition` returns a coordinate on the screen.